# How to filter using a condition in NLog with C#

Tags: c#, filtering, conditional-statements, nlog

I am having an issue creating an NLog target filter in C#. I am trying to create a filter to log to two different targets. I have this working with a condition based off of the message contents containing a matching string. The issue is that I can't seem to get the condition working with the machinename or event-context contents.

This will work as expected with the use of the message itself:

```
var newRule = new LoggingRule("*", logLevel, someWrapper);
newRule.DefaultFilterResult = FilterResult.Ignore;
newRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter()
{
    Condition = "contains(message, 'string')",
    Action = FilterResult.Log
});
config.LoggingRules.Add(newRule);
```

These do not work:

```
Condition = "contains(machinename, 'string')"
Condition = "equals(machinename, 'string')"
Condition = "machinename == 'string')"
Condition = "contains(event-context:item=SomeItem, 'string')"
Condition = "equals(event-context:item=SomeItem, 'string')"
Condition = "event-context:item=SomeItem == 'string')"
```

The error I will see for the above will be:

> "Unexpected token: ==" OR "Unexpected toekn: ,"

I am not sure if I have the format wrong maybe? I have tried several different options but I just can't seem to get the conditional filter working with machinename or more specifically the event-context.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Is `machinename` an string variable, or the actual text that you want to compare to?

Comment: are you sure you aren't looking for ${machinename}?

Comment: See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MachineName-Layout-Renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing on your condition are some single quotes around it.

```
var stringToCompare = "sometext";
var stringCondition = "'${machinename}' == '" + stringToCompare + "'";

...

newRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter()
{
    Condition = stringCondition,
    Action = FilterResult.Log
});
```

Comment: This will compile, but what the use of comparing "machinename" to "string"? I think we are looking for `${machinename}`. See my answer

Comment: You're right, it should be using the `${...}`, but your answer still doesn't execute properly as this `"${machinename} == 'string'"` condition will still throw an exception: `Invalid punctuation: $`. 
I'll update my answer to match [this similar issue](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1901)

Answer (score 2):

NLog 4.6.7 introduces the new `NLog.Filters.WhenMethodFilter` that takes a lambda as input-parameter.

If you want to do filtering without making use of NLog LayoutRenderers. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages

Answer (score 1):

In conditions you could use layout renderers, but you need the `${...}` syntax,

so this will work:

```cs
Condition = "contains(${machinename}, 'string')"
Condition = "equals(${machinename}, 'string')"
Condition = "${machinename} == 'string'"
Condition = "contains(${event-context:item=SomeItem}, 'string')"
Condition = "equals(${event-context:item=SomeItem}, 'string')"
Condition = "${event-context:item=SomeItem} == 'string'"
```

See also the [docs of the conditions in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter#conditions)

> Condition Language
>   The filter expressions are written in a special mini-language. The language consists of:
>
> - relational operators: ==, !=, <, <=, >= and >
>
>   - Note: Some predefined XML characters may need to be escaped. For example, if you try to use the '<' character, the XML parser will interpret it as an opening tag which results in an error in the configuration file. Instead, use the escaped version of '<' (<) in this context.
> - boolean operators: and, or, not
> - string literals which are always evaluated as layouts - ${somerenderer}
> - boolean literals - true and false
> - numeric literals - e.g. 12345 (integer literal) and 12345.678 (floating point literal)
> - log level literals - LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Debug, ... LogLevel.Fatal
> - predefined keywords to access the most common log event properties - level, message and logger
> - braces - to override default priorities and group expressions together
> - condition functions - to perform string and object tests
> - Single quotes should be escaped with another single quote.

All possible layout renderers could be found here [https://nlog-project.org/config](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers) (tab 'layout-renderers')

The official docs how to filter in NLog could be found here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages